# moving a div when required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to move a div up/down wrt another div. Just like News and events div in the website [***neduet***](http://www.neduet.edu.pk/) (screen below)
I searched the web and found some good links ***[here](http://jsbin.com/ubexej/1/edit)*** and ***[here](http://www.thecodepress.info/2013/03/move-html-div-with-css-and-javascript.html#.Ua6hMtIweT9)*** but the issue is if i click up up up it goes up and disappears at some point.

 **what i want** is when i press or hover a button, it checks the div position. if the div is hidden up then it should move up else no action should be performed. The link of neduet is a good example of that.

[image]

Edit:
I am newbie to `javascript` and `jquery` so a working example or a link might be helpful.

Comment: without looking at their code, do you think this could be done by having a div, with an overflow, and controlling the scrolling of that overflow? I feel like i've done this in the past in that manner. EDIT: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362/scrolling-overflowed-divs-with-javascript

Comment: Have you tried using offset(), position(), scrollTop() etc to check the position of the div you are moving?

Comment: Check the position of div whether it will be disappear or not and then perform the action.

Comment: use a container div within which you will allow your div to move. Use that conatiner to define the boundary. Disable your div movement outside that container.

Comment: For reference you can see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970074/adding-a-limit-to-moving-a-div-with-arrow-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not the best with math, but basically you need to find out how much your scrolling content has moved, and stop it from moving when it has moved too far up or down. I have created a similar thing to what yo umay be trying to achieve, here http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/nHuri

I get the height of the container and the height of the content, and then check that the amount the content has scrolled minus the height of the container, is less than the height of the content. It's all very confusing to my math weak brain, but perhaps you can figure out an easier method. At any rate, my example works.

You need to be careful with how much you scroll the content by, as well as how quick the animation is completed, and how often the interval is fired.

I'll attempt to clean up the working code example, but here it is...

```
var scrollamnt = 0, timer, $content = $('#content');
var theoff, scroll = true;

var sHeight = $content.height(), 
    cHeight = $('#scrollC').height(),
    oHeight;

$('#up, #down').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $this = $(this).attr('id');

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        theoff = $content.offset();      
        oHeight = (-theoff.top + cHeight);


      if ($this === 'down' && (oHeight < sHeight)) {
            scrollamnt -= 10;
            scroll = true;
        } else if ($this === 'up' && scrollamnt < 0) {
            scrollamnt += 10;
            scroll = true;
        } else
            scroll = false;

        if (scroll) {
            $content.animate({
                'margin-top' : scrollamnt
            }, 0, 'linear');
            //end animate
        }//end if
    }, 10);
    //end interval*/

}).bind('mouseout', function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Comment: +1 your example looks perfect as desired. i will see this later tonight. Thanks

Comment: I want 1 horizontal as well. so i made an effort http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DipEG but how to add images horizontal instead of vertical in content

Comment: good question! One way is to set the width, such as 1500px. But there may be a better way... http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/Egfks

Comment: It is not working in my page neither the images are loading in content div nor the mouseOver is working. Do i need to use any jquery link or etc for that. My page already contain two jquery links of 1.9.1 and 1.3.2.

Comment: just use the latest jquery CDN, 2.0.0. You only need to include one version. Got to scriptsrc.net or developers.google. You will need to include the script within $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: updated my codepen so it scrolls to the end of the image and stops. Also dynamically sets the width of the image container by getting the width of all the images. http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/zovbe

Comment: Still the same issue after adding latest jquery. where to include $(document).ready(function(){}); can you give me a working example with all included. Please!

Comment: if you create a new javascript file, then you can place the $(document).ready anywhere, and make sure a click events are within it. other functions dont need to be contained within. Its the same if you create it inline in your html document. Just contain your script between the appropriate <script> tags...